# Determine how long tabs '\t' are on a line

Tags: text-processing, control-characters

In a text processing field is there a way to know if a tab is 8 characters in length (the default length) or less?

For example, if I have a sample file with tab delimiter and the content of a field fit in less than one tab (≤7), and if I have a tab after that, then that tab will be only ‘tab size – field size’ in length.

Is there a way to get the total length of tabs on a line? I'm not looking for the number of tabs (i.e. 10 tabs should not return 10) but the character length of those tabs.

For the following input data (tab delimited between fields and only one tab):

```
field0  field00 field000        last-field
fld1    fld11   fld001  last-fld
fd2     fld3    last-fld
```

I expect to count length of tabs in each line, so

```
11
9
9
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `TAB` character is a control character which when sent to a terminal¹ makes the terminal's cursor move to the next tab-stop. By default, in most terminals, the tab stops are 8 columns apart, but that's configurable.

You can also have tab stops at irregular intervals:

```
$ tabs 3 9 11; printf '\tx\ty\tz\n'
  x     y z
```

Only the terminal knows how many columns to the right a TAB will move the cursor.

You can get that information by querying the cursor position from the terminal before and after the tab has been sent.

If you want to make that calculation by hand for a given line and assuming  that line is printed at the first column of the screen, you'll need to:

- know where the tab-stops are²
- know [the display width of every character](/q/245013)
- know the width of the screen
- decide whether you want to handle other control characters like `\r` (which moves the cursor to the first column) or `\b` that moves the cursor back...)

It can be simplified if you assume the tab stops are every 8 columns, the line fits in the screen and there are no other control characters or characters (or non-characters) that your terminal cannot display properly.

With GNU `wc`, if the line is stored in `$line`:

```
width=$(printf %s "$line" | wc -L)
width_without_tabs=$(printf %s "$line" | tr -d '\t' | wc -L)
width_of_tabs=$((width - width_without_tabs))
```

`wc -L` gives the width of the widest line in its input. It does that by using `wcwidth(3)` to determine the width of characters and assuming the tab stops are every 8 columns.

For non-GNU systems, and with the same assumptions, see [@Kusalananda's approach](/a/389267). It's even better as it lets you specify the tab stops but unfortunately currently doesn't work with GNU `expand` (at least) when the input contains multi-byte characters or 0-width (like combining characters) or double-width characters.

---

¹ note though that if you do `stty tab3`, the tty device line discipline will take over the tab processing (convert TAB to spaces based on its own idea of where the cursor might be before sending to the terminal) and implement tab stops every 8 columns. Testing on Linux, it seems to handle properly CR, LF and BS characters as well as multibyte UTF-8 ones (provided `iutf8` is also on) but that's about it. It assumes all other non-control characters (including zero-width, double-width characters) have a width of 1, it (obviously) doesn't handle escape sequences, doesn't wrap properly... That's probably intended for terminals that can't do tab processing.

In any case, the tty line discipline does need to know where the cursor is and uses those heuristics above, because when using the `icanon` line editor (like when you enter text for applications like `cat` that don't implement their own line editor), when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>, the line discipline needs to know how many BS characters to send to *erase* that Tab character for display. If you change where the tab stops are (like with `tabs 12`), you'll notice that Tabs are not erased properly. Same if you enter double-width characters before pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

---

² For that, you could send tab characters and query the cursor position after each one. Something like:

```
tabs=$(
  saved_settings=$(stty -g)
  stty -icanon min 1 time 0 -echo
  gawk -vRS=R -F';' -vORS= < /dev/tty '
    function out(s) {print s > "/dev/tty"; fflush("/dev/tty")}
    BEGIN{out("\r\t\33[6n")}
    $NF <= prev {out("\r"); exit}
    {print sep ($NF - 1); sep=","; prev = $NF; out("\t\33[6n")}'
  stty "$saved_settings"
)
```

Then, you can use that as `expand -t "$tabs"` using @Kusalananda's solution.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ expand file | awk '{ print gsub(/ /, " ") }'
11
9
9
```

The POSIX `expand` utility expands tabs to spaces. The `awk` script counts and outputs the number of substitutions needed to replace all spaces on each line.

To avoid counting any preexisting spaces in the input file:

```
$ tr ' ' '@' <file | expand | awk '{ print gsub(/ /, " ") }'
```

where `@` is a character that is guaranteed not to exist in the input data.

If you want 10 spaces per tab instead of the ordinary 8:

```
$ tr ' ' '@' <file | expand -t 10 | awk '{ print gsub(/ /, " ") }'
9 
15
13
```

Comment: You'd want to replace spaces with some other one-width character (like `x`) before calling `expand` otherwise, you'd also be counting the spaces that were initially in the input as well.

Comment: `expand` also assumes tab-stops every 8 columns (though you can change that with options). Note that the GNU implementation doesn't support multi-byte characters (let alone 0-width or double-width ones). IIRC the FreeBSD one is OK.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Unless, of course, that is part of the plan to count the width of the 0x09s in with the 0x20s ;-)

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -F/\\t/ -lpe '$c = 0; $F[-1] eq "" or pop @F; $_ = (map { $c += 8 - (length) % 8 } @F)[-1]' file
```

Alternatively:

```
perl -MList::Util=reduce -lpe \
    '@F = split /\t/, $_, -1; pop @F if $F[-1] ne ""; $_ = reduce { $a + $b } map { 8 - (length) % 8 } @F' file
```

You can change 8 above with some other value if you want TABs to have a different length.

Answer (score 2):

Also using `expand`, but with bash parameter manipulation to count the number of spaces:

```
$ line=$'field0\tfield00\tfield000\tlast-field'
$ tabs2spaces=$(expand <<<"$line")
$ only_spaces=${tabs2spaces//[^ ]/}    # remove all non-space characters
$ echo "${#only_spaces}"
11
```